# Scala - java.lang.VerifyError with simple function

Tags: java, function, scala, verifyerror

Actually I use my code in a html parser. But here I rewrite it for test.

```
def parse: Int = {
  var texts = Array("a.b.c.d.1321,123.f")
  for (text <- texts) {
    var lines = text.split("\\.")
    return try { lines(4).replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").toInt } catch { case _ => 0 }
  }
  0
}
```

Call `parse`, I got this exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: $anonfun$parse$1, method: apply signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/runtime/Nothing$;) Inconsistent stack height 0 != 3
        at .parse(<console>:10)
        at .<init>(<console>:10)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:11)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My question is why does the code raise that exception?

**Edited**

*Please don't mention about the coding style, just focus on the exception. Because the code can be compiled successfully.*

**Edited**

Change a little of result:

```
def parse: Int = {
  var texts = Array("a.b.c.d.1321,123.f")
  for (text <- texts) {
    var lines = text.split("\\.")
    return try { lines(4).replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").toInt } catch { case _ => -1 }
  }
  0
}
```

If I don't use `for` loop, it is ok:

```
def parse: Int = {
  var text = "a.b.c.d.1321,123.f"
  var lines = text.split("\\.")
  return try { lines(4).replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").toInt } catch { case _ => -1 }
}
```

But I'm still confused about the first case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be because you're returning the result of the entire `try` block.  If you move your `return` inside the block, it's fine:

```
try { return lines(4).replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").toInt } catch { case _ => return 0 }
```

It looks like a compiler bug related to returning the `try` block inside a `for` loop.  Notice that this works fine:

```
def parse: Int = {
  return try { 1 } catch { case _ => 0 }
  0
}
```

while this fails:

```
def parse: Int = {
  for (x <- List(1))
    return try { 1 } catch { case _ => 0 }
  0
}
```

Comment: Thanks dhg, I got it. I have reported a bug here: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5380